# Rails is still trying to load a deleted asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4 project. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121933/source-maps-in-ruby-on-rails-through-sprockets), "Rails 4 does not have source maps either. As far as I know, and as of today, this will only be part of rails 5."

I guess I have to live without source maps in Rails 4 if I am using Sprockets for precompiling. The issue is I included a vendor jquery library, which included its own source map. The location was in `vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.js.map`.

Every time I loaded page, I would get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery.nanoscroller.js.map"):
```

It was annoying me so I deleted the file from vendor. Now that file does not exist anywhere. There is no .map extensions in any of the assets directories of my project.

I then deleted `public/assets` folder to ensure that Rails is not serving from the public cached assets. It should now use Rack Middleware to compile assets on each request and since that .map file is gone, it should not be compiled. However, after deleting the public/assets and restarting server, I still get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery.nanoscroller.js.map"):
```

I even tried adding the following to development just to reassure it is set to false:

```
config.serve_static_files = false
```

(With this setting, it should NOT be serving files from public/assets).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a Rails problem. Your browser trying to get the source map.
According to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map you should find a magic comment in the nanoscroller js file. Delete the comment or disable source maps in the browser settings.

Example of comment:
`//# sourceMappingURL=http://example.com/path/to/your/sourcemap.map`

Source map settings for browsers: https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/336c4982194bcb02ef8a